# how to switch between two background color of the same button on button click

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm am very new to android programming. 
i am trying to switch button color on button click.

i tried to get the button color in the if statement but im getting an error.

thank you in advance for anyone who will answer..

```
//ONCLICK INFORMATION BUTTON
bt_more_info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override                
public void onClick(View v) {
      String more_info   = getResources().getString(R.string.more_info);
      String less_info   = getResources().getString(R.string.less_info);


      if(bt_more_info.getResources().getColor(R.color.material_yellow)){
         //bt_more_info.setText(less_info);                         
         bt_more_info.setBackgroundResource(R.color.button_white);
         bt_more_info.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_grey));

      }else if(bt_more_info.getResources().getColor(R.color.button_white)){
         //bt_more_info.setText(more_info);
         bt_more_info.setBackgroundResource(R.color.material_yellow);
       bt_more_info.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_button));
      }else{
         bt_more_info.setText("logic error");
      }
   }
});
```

[here is the image of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCRgy.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many way for what you want.

one of easy way is add a boolean value for checked.

for example,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView bt_more_info;
    private Boolean isClicked = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bt_more_info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        bt_more_info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isClicked) {
                    bt_more_info.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.more_info));
                    bt_more_info.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
                    bt_more_info.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    isClicked = false;
                } else {
                    bt_more_info.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.less_info));
                    bt_more_info.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
                    bt_more_info.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    isClicked = true;
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```